# how to see line coverage in Bullseye

Tags: code-coverage, bullseye

Recently I started using BullseyeCoverage.
I'm going through the steps: compiling with BullseyeCoverage, running some test cases on the binaries created, generating a coverage report.

In the coverage report there are: function coverage, and condition/decision coverage. However, there is no line coverage. I tried to find a way of generating line coverage statistics, unsuccessfully. I thought of using covbr to this end, but, I need something that will cover all of my sources altogether.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bullseye does not support line coverage (which is also called statement coverage).For reasons, see http://www.bullseye.com/statementCoverage.html